# JScript tag on SO becomes JavaScript tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

First to clear any confusion, JScript is **NOT** JavaScript.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617402/how-to-determine-if-a-given-path-is-a-file-or-folder) no matter how hard I try, it's not possible to change the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) into the more proper [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) tag - the `jscript` tag is recognized, I can select it, I can save the edit and..... the `javascript` tag appears instead.

I guess it's "global" problem with the `jscript` tag but don't want to litter SO with test questions.

**Edit**: looks like it's not relevant anymore:
[We should "desynonymize" [tag:jscript] and [tag:javascript]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112745/we-should-desynonymize-tagjscript-and-tagjavascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it's true that [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) != [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), thanks to synonyms it is as far as stackoverflow's concerned.

*<TeachingGrandmaToSuckEggs>The most common meaning when someone talks about JScript is the Microsoft implementation of ECMAScript (which is usually referred to as JavaScript), i.e. primarily in the browser.</TeachingGrandmaToSuckEggs>* Unfortunately that means that the majority of people *think* that they're the same. In an ideal world we'd be able to have the two as separate tags and everyone would be able to choose appropriately. This isn't an ideal world though.

How about a new tag? One of these:

- [jscript-scripting](/questions/tagged/jscript-scripting)
- [windows-jscript](/questions/tagged/windows-jscript)
- [wsh-jscript](/questions/tagged/wsh-jscript)

None are ideal, really, but probably stand a better chance of acceptance than any request to separate [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) from [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: What baffles me the most is that I can choose `jscript` tag, in the preview it's showing OK but when saving the edit.. nada. Just delete `jscript` then.. :/

Comment: @Shadow - the intent behind it doing that is good... it's just that jscript/javascript is an edge case where they're *usually* synonyms, but not always. It's a better solution than expecting everyone to choose "internet-explorer" rather than "ie" (because you *know* that not everyone will choose the "right" tag), for example, but nothing's every perfect =) That said, perhaps there are better ways of handling tag replacement than the "automagic" way it happens now.

Comment: thanks, that question now has `windows-scripting` tag so it's fairly OK but still, I prefer the Preview to be more accurate. Thanks for all the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

and

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

Comment: So there's no way to add `jscript` tag to questions?

Comment: @Shadow not once it is mapped as a synonym of another tag, but the existing questions with that tag will retain that tag