# We should "desynonymize" [tag:jscript] and [tag:javascript]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

A few questions I've run into lately are somewhat confusing, because they are vaguely asking about client-side operations and tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  This can lead to users posting answers that are web related and not client related, or to situations like the one that [arose in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181478/how-to-make-an-input-from-command-line-in-jscript/), where my editing the question *and* answering the question became sort of a conflict of interest.

It seems likely, in the two instances of this that I've run into in this week alone, that the OP originally specified [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) for the question, which would have automatically synonymized to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  The questions are too vague with the latter.

In order to clarify these questions from web-related questions, I've been adding [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh).  In this case, however, because I'd also answered the question I was accused of editing the question to fit my answer.  It could be that the assumptions I made were wrong, though I believe it's highly unlikely and I think that's probably a topic for a different post.

There's also a [support request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86934/jscript-tag-on-so-becomes-javascript-tag) complaining about this problem, and it does appear to be causing confusion.

JScript is a flavour of ECMAScript, as is JavaScript, so I can understand the desire to have the synonym, but I think in this case an exception should be made.

Examples:

- [How to make an input from command line in JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181478/how-to-make-an-input-from-command-line-in-jscript/) (Conflicted answers, assuming browser or wsh)
- [query a process by PID windows javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149556/query-a-process-by-pid-windows-javascript) (Comments required OP to clarify)
- [How to get the main window handle of a process using JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708151/how-to-get-the-main-window-handle-of-a-process-using-jscript) (First answer assumes browser)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Can you add to your question a few examples of where this is causing problems.

Comment: @Kev: I'll see if I can find some more.  It's difficult to find examples that *haven't been fixed* because [tag:javascript] is a very popular tag.

Comment: I've desynonymised that tag. Can you create a new tag wiki for it, and perhaps labour the point that it's not the same as javascript

Comment: You'll probably need to edit the javascript tag wiki to reflect this change as well.

Comment: @Kev: cheers, will do.

Comment: Actually, don't worry about the javascript tag. I sorted that.

Comment: Isn't ActionScript (the language used for flash) another ECMAScript flavour?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - it is but like JScript the use-case is different. When folks tag as javascript they're 99% of the time asking about browser side javascript. I think there's a valid distinction in this case. I think people are mistakenly using the tags to taxonimise rather than synonymise.

Comment: @Kev Yes, I just wanted to show another example which is not synonymised (but could be, if using this wrong idea).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann ah gotcha. @andy Ok..I've fixed a few of these `wsh` questions, you're welcome to carry on, but take care just to do a few at a time so as not to flood the front page with "bumps".

Comment: OK! Synonym was removed and now we have a lot of questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431809/posting-forms-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax). Why is it tagged with 'jscript'?

Comment: BTW, Microsoft doesn't call this language JScript anymore. Example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232211 "WSH supports scripts written in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) or **JavaScript**".

Comment: @thorn: many people still confuse the two, but I would argue that a synonym could cause many problems than it solves.  As for your second link, that is from an article about Windows 2000 and probably an error.  *Everywhere* on MSDN, WSH articles refer to 'JScript', not 'Javascript'.  It's true that Microsoft do not refer to Internet Explorer's script engine as JScript anymore, however, which is all the more reason to keep the tags separate.  [tag:javascript] for web-based scripting, [tag:jscript] for WSH scripts.  Don't forget that you can edit or suggest edits for tags depending on your rep.

Comment: @AndyE'shead I still don't understand you. It's the same language. Just different environments. IMHO, [tag:wsh] should be used to indicate the environment and [tag:javascript] should be used to indicate the language. MS uses (used) "JScript" as the name for the language not because of some technical difference, but just because of corporate political issues that are largely outdated nowadays.

Comment: @thorn: I disagree completely. JScript may also be referred to as Javascript, but Javascript may not be referred to as JScript―hence the synonym didn't work and it was reversed. The most appropriate course of action is to educate people incorrectly referring to Javascript as JScript, because this is never right. As pointed out in the question and accepted answer, the use case of JScript is broader than Javascript and synonymising them leads to confusion. Please feel free to post a separate answer with some links to where the synonym would vastly improve the clarity of the question body.

Comment: "JavaScript" is in the first place just a popular name of this language and only in the second place, it's a name of a specific dialect (Netscape's and Mozilla's one). The official name is ECMAScript, but almost everybody refers to the langauage as JavaScript. That's why it's the main name of the tag and [tag:ecmascript] is just a synonym. When you write a program for WSH or for node.js you still use the same language, so the same tag should be used, [tag:javascript].

Comment: @AndyE'shead "Javascript may not be referred to as JScript". It's not true. Microsoft does this all the time.

Comment: @AndyE'shead How can a language have a more narrow use case than one of its implementations has? It's impossible.

Comment: @thorn: when Microsoft refer to JScript, they always mean their implementation of ECMAScript and never Javascript. Rather than tirelessly trying to convince you that the two things are not the same and therefore shouldn't be synonymised, I refer you back to my statement of requesting that you provide evidence of the lack of synonym causing confusion across the site in the form of an answer and objection, much like the existence of the synonym did when I originally posted this question.  Either that, or post your down vote in disagreement. Thanks :-)

Comment: @AndyE'shead I need 125 reputation to vote down :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Stack Overflow user and not a moderator I would support this request. JScript whilst being a flavour of ECMAScript isn't "normal" Javascript, the use case is entirely different.

It's a bit like lumping all of the `vb` flavours under one tag (`vbscript`, `vba`, `excel-vba`, `access-vba` etc), yes they are syntactically similar, but they each have their own defining characteristic and purpose. Or even more fun, making `node.js` a synonym of Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of `node.js` as an example too, though there are differences in that area.  On the flip side of the coin, though, there are some people who refer to *"JavaScript"* as *"JScript"* because they think the latter is just another word for it.  So removing the synonym could just lead to issues where people say *"JScript"* and mean *"JavaScript"*.  I realize I'm not making a good argument for my case, there, but I guess the community needs to decide which is the bigger problem.

Comment: @AndyE'shead: Actually, that's an argument *for* your case. In that case people are using the wrong term, and if we break the synonym, we'll teach them!