# Syntax highlighting for questions tagged [jscript]

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Since [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [broke up with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112745/we-should-desynonymize-tagjscript-and-tagjavascript) [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript), it's been looking a little pale.  Can we get the syntax highlighter to apply some colour to it?

Comment: As a workaround, you can always add `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the code block to achieve that.

Comment: @slhck: I know that, and so do you, but not everybody else does :-)