# Attempt to create a new tag silently fails

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just tried to tag a new question with a 'googe-charts' tag. The tag appears rendered as the other tags (upon typing a space after the tag chars), but on saving the edit the tag disappears.

I assume there is some attempt at moderating new tags going on, but there is no feedback to that effect. I think it needs something like - 'this is a new tag and will be considered....'

For the record here's the question:

[Showing UTC datetime on a google charts axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165516/showing-utc-datetime-on-a-google-charts-axis)

Answer (score 5):

You mean google-charts tag and the reason you can't add it is because it has a [Tag Synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms):

> [image]

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-visualization/synonyms):

> The following tags will be remapped to google-visualization
>   google-charts, google-charts-api, and google-geochart

Also, when trying to add the tag to a question you can see it will be remapped:

> [image]

If you think this is wrong and google-charts should be on its own, start MSO discussion about it, and if enough people will agree, a moderator can remove the Synonym. This [has happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112745/we-should-desynonymize-tagjscript-and-tagjavascript).

Comment: Thanks. So it's a minor issue but I think the UI feedback could have been clearer about what was actually happening. I interpreted the 'also' tags as being further suggestions, i.e. if you're tagging with 'abc' then consider tagging with 'def' and 'ghi' too.

Comment: I see. Asking for a rewording or adding a visual warning "this tag will be remapped" sounds like a valid request indeed.